# SKNode subclass with custom init method

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, sknode

I'm trying to subclass an SKNode class by using a custom init method.
My custom init method looks like this:

```
//interface
@interface BlocksLayer : SKNode
-(instancetype)initWithDirection(BlocksLayerMotionDirection)direction;
@end

//implementation
-(instancetype)initWithDirection:(BlocksLayerMotionDirection)direction{
    self=[super init];
    if (self) {
       self.direction=direction;
       [self makeLayer];
     }
     return self;  
}

-(void)makeLayer{
    //scene size has always width=0 and height=0
    NSLog(@"%f",self.scene.size.width);
    NSLog(@"%f",self.scene.size.height);
}
```

When I initialize the class with my custom method scene.width and scene.height are always zero.

Instead if I use the static **node** method initialization the scene.size contains valid values.

Do you have any idea what is the problem?

Is this a correct way to subclass a SKNode and is it a valid strategy to implement a non-static custom initialization method?

Many thanks,

Domenico

Comment: Are you sure that an `SKNode` contains a `SKScene`?  I'm pretty sure that it's the other way around...  The values you are reading might only be valid after adding to a scene as well, or you could just pass in a width and height to use.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.
Of course the main SKScene is ok, because I have other custom SKNode initialized with the static node method and I have no problem with them.
It seems that when I don't call the static node method (for instance [MyNode node]) as initialization, the scene.size it will available after the initWithSize  scene method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the `[SKNode node];` method sets up the `self.scene` property (with most likely default values, something like 1024x768).  The code you provided doesn't create the `self.scene` property, and therefore it doesn't have default values.

When the `SKNode` is added to the scene, the `self.scene` property will point to the `SKScene` that it was added to (this will always point to the root `SKScene` even if it is nested like SKScene->SKNode->SKNode).  *Then* you can read the `self.scene.size` to get the size of the scene.

If you need to read the values before adding to the scene, you can do:

1. Pass in a reference to the `SKScene` in your custom init method and set `self.scene` to it.
2. You can pass the size in as a parameter.
3. You can hard code it in.

These are ranked by what I would do.

Comment: @DomenicoVacchiano  No problem, let me know how it goes.

Comment: So at last if I understood correctly, we can say that if we want to write a custom init method for a SKNode subclass and we have to use the related SKScene reference, we have to pass as param the reference of the current SKScene...right?